# SpreadsheetLight get numeric value from cell formula

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Does anyone know if it possible to retrieve the numeric value of a formula in SpreadsheetLight?  if not is possible to read the formula in OpenXml as numeric?

I need to return 7.07 for cellValue(8,1)

```
  public static void TestSlWorkbook()
  {
     SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();
     sl.SetCellValue(1, 1, 1.01);
     sl.SetCellValue(2, 1, 1.01);
     sl.SetCellValue(3, 1, 1.01);
     sl.SetCellValue(4, 1, 1.01);
     sl.SetCellValue(5, 1, 1.01);
     sl.SetCellValue(6, 1, 1.01);
     sl.SetCellValue(7, 1, 1.01);

     sl.SetCellValue(8, 1, "=Sum(A1:A7)");

  }
```

Comment: Does `Evaluate()` work in your environment?

Comment: No, I am using the plugin from spreadsheetlight.com

Comment: Maybe you should use Interop it's easy and the most common way. Im sure you'll get more help

Comment: Unfortunately, I was told not to use any COM objects for this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SpreadsheetLight doesn't have a calculation engine, so there's no evaluation of cell formulas (as of current status). The values you get are either what Excel has calculated previously (which means it's probably outdated by the time you want the value) or 0 (because SpreadsheetLight has no calculation engine, so it defaults to either 0 or empty string).

Disclosure: I wrote SpreadsheetLight.

Comment: @Vincent Tan Is there a way to copy a worksheet from one workbook to another using Spreadsheetlight?

Comment: Are there any other free Excel libaries (except EPPlus and NPIO) which provide a calculation engine?

Answer (score 0):

SpreadsheetLight has pretty good documentation on their site (as a chm download).  It did not work right for me, so I unzipped it and accessed the html files directly (a chm is a fancy type of zip file).

Have you tried sl.GetCellValueAsDouble or any other method of SLDocument?

Comment: I have tried GetCellValueAsDouble and GetCellValueAsDecimal and it returns 0; I downloaded the chm file but was unable to read it. I will try your way of unzipping it. Thanks,

Comment: Lou, I unpacked the chm file and read everything with formula in the name, but didn't find anything. I'm starting to think its no possible! Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I did some searching on OpenXML calculation of formulas and it stops at storing formulas, the last value that was calculated (as in the last time the document was saved by Excel), and a flag whether the cell needs to be recalculated, but no calculation engine to evaluate the formula.